# Microsoft.Cpp.Clang.targets error : Element <ExceptionHandling> has an invalid value of "Async"

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, clang++

I am trying to build a project with platform toolset clang3.8 on Visual Studio 2015, I get an error **Microsoft.Cpp.Clang.targets(210,5): error : Element  has an invalid value of "Async"**.

If i physically locate the Microsoft.Cpp.Clang.targets and remove all the occurrences of line  ExceptionHandling="%(ClCompile.ExceptionHandling)" from that file,the build succeeds,but that is more of a hack.

We are now moving our code to CI builds and it is not possible to do this on Jenkins,is there any visual studio 2015 setting that can help me build without changing the
Microsoft.Cpp.Clang.targets physical file?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to disable  C++ exception handling in your code by using  `/EHsc`? Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation->Enable C++ Exceptions ->No. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4t3saedz.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. The detail steps to set compiler options:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311065/how-to-modify-default-compiler-options-for-the-visual-c-compiler

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I did try disabling C++ Exceptions,but that led to multiple errors,when i did input the flag from command line as suggested,the error was,no file /EHs exists,just to mention,its a cross platform project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, there were boost::regex source files included in my source code, the files were added but weren't used anywhere in the source code except for some modules which could easily be removed as the functionality achieved by it was 
implemented in another manner by me. On removing the boost::regex, the build succeeded. 
Don't have a logical answer yet to it as this was just hit and try.